Discrepancies in Output with Ray Parallelization of ODE Propagation
I am using Ray to parallelize my ODE propagation code, which employs solve_ivp with the lsoda solver. For performance, the ODE code also uses Numba JIT. While the code runs correctly in a single-threaded environment and with multiprocessing, I am encountering small discrepancies in the output when using Ray for parallelization compared to the single-threaded runs. The discrepancies are on the order of 6e-7 and only occurs on a small subset of samples. How can i reduce the discrepancies and ensure the output matches?
So far I have tried the following:

Using ray.init(local_mode=True) yields results that match those of multiprocessing.
The discrepancy persists regardless of the number of Ray actors used.
Discrepancies persists when using Ray on a single known problematic task.
I tested Dask as an alternative and its output matches exactly with Ray's output, although both differ from multiprocessing results by up to 6e-7 for some samples.

